# Django optional, non-capturing string in URLs

Tags: python, django, regex, rest

I am trying to add prefix parameter to our api url's for our application implemented in Python Django. It is currently like this

```
urlpatterns= [
   path("api/", include(
   [
      path("books/", include(books.urls)),
      path("events/", include(events.urls)),
      path("meetings/<str:group_id>/", handle_meetings)
   ])
)
]
```

Now what I want to do is make this api a non-capturing and optional parameter. By non-capturing I mean I want the parameter to be in the URL but not go to the views and handlers. I don't want to add it as a parameter to my views and handlers because I won't use it for now.

And I want it to be optional. I will now show what I want to achieve in examples

/api/books    - should work

/api_v1/books    - should work

/books  - should work

This being non-capturing is not the most meaningful function because the user can basically enter anything. But it is just a temporary solution and this is how we decided to go. Is this even possible?

If this is not possible, I am okay with giving up on making it non-capturing as well. I still couldn't fix it. So in that case you can think of it as this.

```
path("books/", include(books.urls)),
path("events/", include(events.urls)),
path("meetings/<str:group_id>/", handle_meetings)
```

I have these. I want all of these to have optional prefix parameter. Same case of accepting requests as above, I will just have to update my handlers in my views in order to use the parameter that I add. You can assume the use_case like we have to add api/ as a prefix but without breaking the production code and without disturbing people using our api. Hence it should be optional.

How can I do this? I am super confused. Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't really see why these should be non-capture. You can simply ignore the parameters. In class-based views, it even is assigned to `self.kwargs` so you can just omit these.

Answer (score 0):

this is a suggestion, if you want `/api/books` and `/books` to be the same endpoints, you can achieve that by creating another API. It would look like this,

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    # URLs with 'api' prefix
    path("api/", include([
        path("books/", include("books.urls")),
        path("events/", include("events.urls")),
        path("meetings/<str:group_id>/", handle_meetings),
    ])),

    # URLs without 'api' prefix (optional)
    path("books/", include("books.urls")),
    path("events/", include("events.urls")),
    path("meetings/<str:group_id>/", handle_meetings),
]
```

I do not understand why you would want `/api_v1/books`, but if you want that too, you could try something like this

```
from django.urls import re_path, include

urlpatterns = [
    # URLs with optional and non-capturing prefix
    re_path(r'^(?:api_[A-Za-z0-9]+/)?', include([
        re_path(r'^books/', include("books.urls")),
        re_path(r'^events/', include("events.urls")),
        re_path(r'^meetings/(?P<group_id>\w+)/', handle_meetings),
    ])),
]
```